# how to convert float into binary in c#?

Tags: c#, serialization, serial-port

I have 2 floats `f1` & `f2`. I need to convert them into binary(e.g. 01010101 10000001 11110000 01011110, i.e.8 bits*4) then send them through a serial port. At the receiving end, after receiving these signals in binary, I need to convert them into float and display them as a string.

My questions are:

1. Is my conversion from float to binary correct?
2. When the signal is received, `textbox3` only displays some random code while `textbox4` is empty. Why is this?

My current codes are as below.

#### To send:

```
byte[] b1 = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(f1), b2 = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(f2);
        if (serialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            serialPort.Write(b1, 0, 4);
            serialPort.Write(b2, 0, 4);
        }
```

#### To receive:

```
private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        byte[] b = new byte[sp.BytesToRead];
        sp.Read(b, 0, sp.BytesToRead);
        Invoke(new Action(() => textBox3.AppendText(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b))));
        float newf = System.BitConverter.ToSingle(b, 0);
        textBox4.Text = newf.ToString();
     }
```

Comment: Good luck, but what is your question?

Comment: Hi thanks for reply! I want to convert float to binary then send by serialport, after receive, convert from binary back to float then display as string.    Q1.Im not sure the way I convert float to binary is correct or not. Q2. when receiving signal, textbox3 only displays some random code and textbox4 is empty.

Comment: Can you please put this comment inside the question?

Answer (score 3):

Several mistakes, you *hope* that you'll get the entire 'package' that was sent.  Serial ports do not work that way.  You'll have to wait until all 8 bytes were received. `Encoding.UTF8` is quite inappropriate, it isn't text.  Write something like this:

```
private byte[] Buffer = new byte[8];
private int Rcved = 0;

private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    Rcved += sp.Read(Buffer, Rcved, 8 - Rcved);
    if (Rcved < 8) return;
    float f1 = BitConverter.ToSingle(Buffer, 0);
    float f2 = BitConverter.ToSingle(Buffer, 4);
    string txt3 = BitConverter.ToString(Buffer);
    string txt4 = String.Format("{0}, {1}", f1, f2);
    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
        textBox3.AppendText(txt3 + Environment.NewLine);
        textBox4.Text = txt4;
    }));
    Rcved = 0;
}
```

Beware a synchronization problem, your program can't properly start up when the device is busy sending, it will only have a 1 in 8 chance to start reading at the correct byte.  Solving this requires a protocol, a very simple one is master-slave where the device doesn't send anything until it is explicitly asked to do so.

And beware of a fire-hose problem, your UI can freeze on the BeginInvoke() calls if they occur too frequently.  In which case you need to improve the UI, no human is going to enjoy looking at a list of numbers flying by faster than he can possibly read anyway.

Comment: hi thank you so much for your help! Im trying to absorb your comment now. Btw, how about my "to send" commands? Is the way I convert float to binary correct? Im quite confused about this, because MSDN shows that bitconverter.getbyte is to convert to hex, not binary. But I cant find other way to convert float to binary,which is like 01010101 10000001 11110000 01011110 format.Thanks!

Comment: Bytes are binary.  If you want to print the 0s and 1s then you'll have to write the code for that.  Very little point, it is going to bore a human to tears *very* quickly.

Comment: Hi I got the code works! Thank you so much! Just one last question, after received signals, only the latest signal would be displayed, as when I sent more than one signal, I could not view all of them from textbox. how should I fix it? for loop?